# How to delete an image from axMapControl component?

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine

I have a problem in arcgis c#. I am using Arcgis axMapControl component and adding image to it but I can not delete image when wanted to delete from axMapControl component... I have get a exception such as " The process cannot access the file C:\Users.. because it is being used by another process "

Thanks for your help.

```
public void Add_map()

  IRasterLayer my_raster = new RasterLayer();
  my_raster.FromFile(path);
  AxMapControl1.AddLayer(my_raster);
--------------------------------------------------
public void Delete_map()

AxMapControl1.DeleteLayer(0);
System.IO.File.delete(path);    //There is a Exception.... This problem...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly delete the raster, since your application still has references to it.
What you need to do, is to delete all references you are holding to it in code, and then delete it using lower level ArcObjects: `IDataset:Delete`